# How can we disable default login in WSO2 EI console?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I installed from WSO2 EI 6.6.0. How can I disable the default EI console login ?
username: admin
password: admin

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the super user admin. You can change the username and password in the configuration file. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Maintaining+Logins+and+Passwords#MaintainingLoginsandPasswords-Changingthesuperadminpassword

Comment: I changed the username and password in <Product>/conf/user-mgt.xml
Still I can login with admin, admin. 
Restarted EI, still the same. 
Even from EI console, I can see the old admin user is there.

Comment: If we change the username too, it will create a new username keeping the old admin credentials as it is. Changing the password only, did the trick. Thanks

Comment: Correction: If we change the username too, it will create a new username keeping the old admin credentials as it is. Still the issue is not resolved

Comment: @PradeepSanjeewa When you change the username and password in the user-mgt.xml, a new user will be added in the user database and it will be marked as super admin. After that you can login to the management console with the new super admin and you can delete the old admin user. (Go to configure -> Users & Roles -> List -> Users)